# UnsatisfiedLinkError Trying to run OpenCV java code cross compiled

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm beating my head against a wall here.  There are a lot of very similar questions but none exactly on point.  I'm sure the answer is staring me in the face.

I'm conducting my first OpenCV cross compile test.  I set up OpenCV 3.1.0 in Eclipse on Windows 10.  Code there runs fine.  From there I created an executable .jar and FTP'd it to a raspberry pi 3 running Jessie.

I installed OpenCV 3.1.0 on the Pi including java support (on the third try).  But I continue to get the same error.

Code:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

public class Hello
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
      Mat mat = Mat.eye( 3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1 );
      System.out.println( "mat = " + mat.dump() );
   }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java310 in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at Hello.main(Hello.java:9)
```

I've found opencv-java310.jar in /usr/local/share/OpenCV/java

And I have tried at the command line both with and without the -D parameter:

```
java -jar HelloEx.jar -D java.library.path=/usr/local/share/OpenCV/java
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like native library is needed to run openCV on raspberry. Quick googling shows me this thread, which probably is what you need: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=108749

Comment: I don't mean to be obtuse about it but these are the kinds of google results that have me beating my head against the wall.  I'm sorry if I'm just not getting it.  That post would require me to remove the opencv 3.1 installation I have, copy over the precompiled binaries from the third party linked there.  I believe you that its looking for native library, I can find the jni.h, tried -cp to that directory from the command line.  No change.

Comment: I'm not sure if you correctly set java.library.path, as in your starting post it is incorrect, please try use it as follows: `java -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/share/OpenCV/java -jar HelloEx.jar` and you also may check if it was set correctly in your java code by adding the following code (just to debug): `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));`.  If it is set correctly, and still does not work, I would check if your user has required permissions on the library folder and files

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you!

Comment: Done, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you correctly set java.library.path, as in your starting post it is incorrect, please try use it as follows: `java -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/share/OpenCV/java -jar HelloEx.jar` and you also may check if it was set correctly in your java code by adding the following code (just to debug): `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));`